# Missing dependency: Cannot read property 'saveToken' of undefined thrown

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm trying to mock an authentication service. I post my login credentials and get a token back, i then save the token.

Basically the test runs if i comment the line:

```
this.authenticationService.saveToken(res.json().token);
```

I injected the service in the test, and this line doesn't affect the output.

My error is "Cannot read property 'saveToken' of undefined thrown"

Here is my service:

```
private authSuccess(res: Response){
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    this.authenticationService.saveToken(res.json().token);
    return res.json();
}

public postLogin(loginData: LoginModel): Observable<any>{
    let body = JSON.stringify(loginData);
    var headers = new Headers();        
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options)
    //success
    .map(this.authSuccess)
    //error          
    .catch(this.handleError);        
}
```

Here is my test:

```
describe('login service tests', () => {    
    let loginService: LoginService;
    let backend: MockBackend;
    let injector: Injector;
    let authenticationService: AuthenticationService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(<any> [
        LoginService,
        AuthenticationService,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        MockBackend,
        provide(Http, {
            useFactory: (mockBackend, defaultOptions) => new Http(mockBackend, defaultOptions),
            deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        })
    ]);

    loginService = <LoginService> injector.get(LoginService);
    backend = <MockBackend> injector.get(MockBackend);
    authenticationService = <AuthenticationService> injector.get(AuthenticationService)
  });

  afterEach(() => backend.verifyNoPendingRequests());

  it('should authenticate with the web api', () => {
      let loginUrl = Constants.loginUrl;
      let loginData:LoginModel = new LoginModel('username', 'password');

      backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => {
        expect(c.request.url).toEqual(loginUrl);
        c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: '{"token": "mockAuth"}' })));
      });

    //Correct login data
    loginService.postLogin(loginData).subscribe((data) => {        
        expect(data.token).toBe('mockAuth');
    });

  });
```

Also, how do you guys debug when running tests? console.log doesn't seem to work and neither does debugger;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it seems the issue was calling the method in the .map section instead of executing everything directly there.

Solution:

delete authsuccess

```
.map((response) => {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.authenticationService.saveToken(response.json().token);
        return response.json();
})
```